# Make get request to web service, get json response and update GUI in Qt

Tags: json, qt, web-services, qt-creator, qtnetwork

Trying to learn **Web Services** with **Qt** (using Qt Creator 4.1.0) and **connecting data to the GUI**. I have read several online examples (most notably: [1](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/archives/access-json-webservice-qt-c), [2](http://ynonperek.com/course/qt/web-service.html) and [3](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/01/17/how-to-send-and-receive-json-requests-in-qt/)) but my low coding level along with the fact that I could not find full examples that were demonstrating my needs lead me here :).

I have created a simple example so that contains all my shortcomings:

- **make an HTTP get request to a (existing) web service** every 30 seconds.
- The web service then responds by **sending a json data object** (see below for such a json example format) which we **receive and parse**.
- Then, **the Qt will display all the parsed json data onto a simple GUI** (see below for how such a GUI looks like.

*json data format - example*:

```
{
    "city": "London",
    "time": "16:42",
    "unit_data": 
        [
            {
                "unit_data_id": "ABC123",
                "unit_data_number": "21"
            }
        ]
}
```

*My simple Qt GUI design (made in Qt Creator)* displaying all the fetched parsed data:
[image: my simple Qt GUI design]

I would really appreciate any full code example that show how we can make a request to a web service and then how to fetch the json response. Finally, how to connect the GUI in Qt to display this data as soon as they are received.

I am just starting studying this area and I am in need of a simple full code example to get me going.

Comment: Have you written the code to *make the HTTP get request to the (existing) web service every 30 seconds*? you show the JSON format and the GUI, but you don't show any code you've tried.

Comment: @Mike I followed some examples with `QNetworkAccessManager` I found, but the lack of any full tutorials and examples for my entry level led to nothing. So, I have no actual code, just several failed code chunk attempts. Any guide and code for the above problem will help me dive into the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fully working example on how to send a GET request with parameters to a web service using [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and parse the JSON response using [`QJsonDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html).

In the example, I am sending a request to `http://uinames.com/` whose responses are encoded in JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "surname":"Doe",
    "gender":"male",
    "region":"United States"
}
```

I am parsing the JSON response and displaying it in a GUI.

[image: Example screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //setup GUI (you could be doing this in the designer)
    QWidget widget;
    QFormLayout layout(&widget);
    QLineEdit lineEditName;
    QLineEdit lineEditGender;
    QLineEdit lineEditRegion;
    auto edits = {&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion};
    for(auto edit : edits) edit->setReadOnly(true);
    layout.addRow("Name:", &lineEditName);
    layout.addRow("Gender:", &lineEditGender);
    layout.addRow("Region:", &lineEditRegion);
    QPushButton button("Get Name");
    layout.addRow(&button);

    //send request to uinames API
    QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
    QObject::connect(&networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
                     [&](QNetworkReply* reply){
        //this lambda is called when the reply is received
        //it can be a slot in your GUI window class
        //check for errors
        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
            for(auto edit : edits) edit->setText("Error");
            networkManager.clearAccessCache();
        } else {
            //parse the reply JSON and display result in the UI
            QJsonObject jsonObject= QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
            QString fullName= jsonObject["name"].toString();
            fullName.append(" ");
            fullName.append(jsonObject["surname"].toString());
            lineEditName.setText(fullName);
            lineEditGender.setText(jsonObject["gender"].toString());
            lineEditRegion.setText(jsonObject["region"].toString());
        }
        button.setEnabled(true);
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
    //url parameters
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("amount", "1");
    query.addQueryItem("region", "United States");
    QUrl url("http://uinames.com/api/");
    url.setQuery(query);
    QNetworkRequest networkRequest(url);
    //send GET request when the button is clicked
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){
        networkManager.get(networkRequest);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        for(auto edit : edits) edit->setText("Loading. . .");
    });

    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### Edit:

Since you asked about how to use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) to trigger the update every one minute, replace the `connect` call of the button `clicked` signal from the code above with something like this:

```
QTimer timer;
QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
    networkManager.get(networkRequest);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    for(auto edit : edits) edit->setText("Loading. . .");
});
timer.start(60000); //60000 msecs = 60 secs
```

As noted in comments, if you are using this in your window class's constructor, you have to make sure that the `networkManager`, `networkRequest`, the GUI components, and the `timer` here are kept alive as long as your window object is running. So, you may choose to allocate them in the heap or as class members.

Comment: That is perfect, even if not with my example, it clearly demonstrates what I was seeking to understand. Thanks. Small question, if I have a `QMainWindow` class does that mean that all your code into the constructor of that class?

Comment: On the same topic as my first question with `QMainWindow`, I tried to copy your code (with some modifications) it in the class but I get many errors; perhaps you would briefly explain how that should work? Thanks

Comment: @nk-fford , I don't have access to your web service that's why I wrote a general example as you asked, the example is indeed working as it it. No, you don't copy all the code to `QMainWindow`'s constructor as it is. The main issue is that `networkManager`, `networkRequest`, and all GUI components need to be kept alive as long as your `QMainWindow` is running. You may choose to allocate them on the heap or as class members. Also, you may want to replace the lambda functions with slots.

Comment: If you are using the designer for your GUI, the GUI components are allocated dynamically by default, and you can access them using the `ui` pointer. The example here demonstrates usage of the `QNetworkAccessManager` and the `QJsonDocument`. Problems you are getting when putting it in your `QMainWindow` are of general C++ language. The reason I wrote all the code in `main` function is for the example to be as minimum and verifiable as possible.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the clarification. Last question: if I wanted to have the get request triggered every 1 minute could you please show how that would look in the code? I get confused with how to replace the button.

Comment: Use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details), and connect its [`timeout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal, to the slot/lambda where the request is initiated (this is the lambda connected to `QPushButton::clicked` in my example).

Comment: I struggle with the timer. Sorry, I am a newbie with all this. Any chance to provide a small chunk of code of the timer so I can see an example of it in your original code please?

Comment: @nk-fford , I have updated the answer. Although I think this should be asked as a [separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156902) about `QTimer` as this is not closely related to using `QNetworkAccessManager` and accessing a web service from Qt.