# Cannot use QNetworkAccessManager with QtConcurrent

Tags: qt, qt5, qthread, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtconcurrent

I'm trying to use `QtConcurrent` for not having to create a new slot for a simple `QNetworkAccessManager::get` request:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QFuture<QNetworkReply*> future = QtConcurrent::run(am, &QNetworkAccessManager::get, QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")));
future.waitForFinished();
```

but what i get is a warning from Qt:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>
> (Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x7fc973f3d100), parent's thread is QThread(0x7fc973c14ec0), current thread is QThread(0x7fc973dc2090)

If code like:

```
QObject *obj = new QObject();
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(obj, &QObject::setParent, new QObject);
future.waitForFinished();
```

works fine and with no warnings and errors, can anyone explain to me what's the difference between the two approaches and what happens behind the scenes of the `QNetworkAccessManager` approach?

Is there a solution for the `QNetworkAccessManager` approach?

Comment: Why are you trying to call the `get` function from the thread pool rather than from the main GUI thread? Normally, one moves functions that take long time to finish. `get` is an asynchronous and is designed to be run from the GUI thread normally.

Comment: Also, you seem to call `waitForFinished()` after the starting the call in the other thread immediately. After seeing that, I couldn't think of any reason for parallelizing such call at all.

Comment: Every `QNetworkAccessManager` is designed to be used only from the thread it was created. you can see that in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details). When calling `get`, Qt tries to create a `QNetworkReply` object for this request, and this object is a child of the `QNetworkAccessManager`. It can **not** create such a child for the parent in a different thread, hence the warning.

Comment: You don't need to create a slot for every `get` call, you can connect to lambda functions. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521698/2666212).

Comment: @Mike After reading your comments I now realize the idiocy I was trying to do...I was somehow expecting that `waitForFinished` waits until `QNetworkReply::finished` gets emitted...which is extremely stupid...
So yea...thanks! :)